# how to remove automatic shutdown in ubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, systemd

So my friend is trying to use an old thinkpad that has Kubuntu on it but we found out that it has an automatic shutdown from 11pm -7pm, that his mother put on it years ago. We managed to get the system to run by messing with the clock in bios and configuring it to make i think it was a different time of day. The problem is we don't know what program is being used to shutdown the pc, We think the shutdown has something to do with system md. We cant connect to the internet because the pc just resets the bios clock every time we connect. So my question is there a way to disable the shutdown without having to reinstall linux.

Comment: Cool mother!. If you guys don't have the root password, the answer is no. And I'm sure hope you don't ;-)

Comment: So you mean 7 am? What happens if you turn the computer back on after 11PM, does it turn itself off unless it is after 7AM/PM? Which version of Kubuntu is it running? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1257748/edit) and add all the new information **inside the question**.

Answer (score 0):

```
last -x | head | tac
```

will show information on shutdowns. It will show the user it was done with. If root you do not need to check for scripts that are user related. If the user you need to find a user script.

Also check `/var/log/auth.log` It will have a registration of shutdowns.

Files to check:

1. `more /etc/crontab`  for the all users cron
2. `crontab -l` for the cron used by user
3. `sudo -i` -> password and then `crontab -l` for the cron used by root.
4. `cd /etc/cron.daily/`
5. [systemd.timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) and [systemd.halt](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-halt.service.html)

Check them all for a shutdown or halt command or a script that is started.

> So my question is there a way to disable the shutdown without having to reinstall linux.

There is never a need to re-install. Rebooting into rescue mode (either from grub or a live session) open ups the machine to all who has access.

Comment: As a father of 3 kids I strongly object to such an answer ;-)

Comment: @kanehekili #2 requires the sudo password ;-)

Comment: @user68186 added :D